# How to change iOS app's background image?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to change my app's whole background image to black, including the status bar and navigation bar, because I want to use black underpainting and gray font color. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the view into UIButton, UILabel, UIImageView, etc.

```
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```